# Irregularity of $\{a^p : p \text{ prime}\}$ using Myhill–Nerode

Tags: regular-languages

Consider the language
$$ L = \{2^k : k \text{ is prime}\}. $$
This language contains, for example, $2^3=222$, $2^5=22222$, $2^7=2222222$, and so on.

I know that $L$ is irregular and so there must exist a set of strings that are pairwise distinguishable with respect to $L$, but I'm struggling to come up with such a set of strings. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand something, but $\Sigma^*$ is regular, but still follows your definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose $2^*$ as your set of words. Indeed, consider the words $2^a,2^b$, where $a < b$. If these words are indistinguishable then for all $c \geq 0$, $a + c$ is prime iff $b + c$ is prime. Since there are infinitely many primes, we can find a prime $p \geq a$. Let $c_1 = p-a$. Since $p$ is prime, so is $b + c_1 = p + (b-a)$. Choosing $c_2 = p-a+(b-a)$, we similarly get that $b + c_2 = p + 2(b-a)$ is prime. Continuing in this fashion, we see that $p + k(b-a)$ is prime for all $k \geq 0$. In particular, $p + p(b-a)$ should be prime. But $p + p(b-a) = p(b-a+1)$ clearly isn't prime. This contradiction shows that $2^a,2^b$ are distinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

Take the sets 2^p where p is prime and the gap between p and the next larger prime is some number g fixed for that set. Sets with different g can be distinguished, and gaps between consecutive primes become arbitrary large.

This applies when you don’t take primes, but numbers f(n) where f(n) / n goes towards infinity. Trivial cases would be squares, cubes, factorials etc. instead of primes. Or any subsets of these.